# “pagechange” event unexpectedly thrown from either Worklight or jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a Single Page `Hybrid/Cordova` app based on `IBM Worklight 6.1` and `jQuery Mobile 1.4`.

At my Home Page I have a popup box which shows a password input and a login button.
When I tap the login button, the jQuery method (shown below) captures the login event and takes me to the Admin Tools page, as I expected.

So far so good, but then suddenly a new “pagechange” event is thrown from either Worklight (wljq.js) or jQuery Mobile (jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js)) and I get kicked back to the Home Page.

Can anyone please help me and figure out what is happening?

```
$('#adminToolsLoginButton').on('tap', function() {
    var password = $('#adminToolsPasswordInput').val();
    if (password === adminToolsPassword) {
        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#adminTools", { } );
    } else {
        WL.Logger.debug('Wrong admin password');
        alert('Wrong admin password');
        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#myHome", { } );
    }
});
```

Best regards,
Magnus.

Comment: the button is `<a>`, `<button>` or `<input>`? welcome to SO :)

Comment: I don't see that jQuery Mobile 1.4 is supported, meaning it hasn't been tested: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=66C745D01E8711E28ACF6F870925FE36

Comment: What makes you think this event is thrown by wljq.js?

Comment: I would also suggest to simplify this by create a new app that only mimics what you're trying to do - basically move between pages see and if you are able to recreate it. If yes, either see what's wrong now that it is isolate, and/or share this test case via dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback.

The problem is now solved!

The problem was related to the jQuery Mobile Popup Widget that wanted to take me back to the page where it was located and was opened from. Is this perhaps a bug?

I solved the problem by using the 'afterclose' event as shown below:

```
        var isLogin = false;

    $('#adminToolsLoginButton').on('tap', function() {
        var password = $('#adminToolsPasswordInput').val();
        if(password === adminToolsPassword){
            isLogin = true;
        }
        else{
            isLogin = false;
            WL.Logger.debug('Wrong admin password');
            alert('Wrong admin password');
        }
    }); 

    $( "#popupAdminLoginDialog" ).on( "popupafterclose", function( event, ui ) {
        if(isLogin){
            $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#adminTools", { } );
        }
        isLogin = false;
    } );
```